# Parsing data from ASCII formatted file in C

Tags: c, parsing, matrix

I am trying to do what's been done here [Read co-ordinates from a txt files using C Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037219/read-co-ordinates-from-a-txt-files-using-c-program) . The data that I am trying to input is in this format:

```
f 10 20 21
f 8 15 11
. . .  .
f 11 12 25
```

The only difference in my point structure is that I have a an extra char to store the letter in the first column (which may or may not be the letter f). I guess im either declaring my char wrong, or I'm calling it in `printf` incorrectly. Either way, I only get the first line read and then my program terminates. Any ideas ?

Here is my MWE below

```
#define FILEPATHtri "/pathto/grid1DT.txt"
#define FILEPATHorg "/pathto/grid1.txt"
#define MAX  4000

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "math.h"

typedef struct
{    
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    char t[1];
}Point;

int main(void) {

    Point *points = malloc( MAX * sizeof (Point) ) ;

    FILE *fp ;
    fp = fopen( FILEPATHtri,"r");

int i = 0;

while(fscanf(fp, "%s %f %f %f ", points[i].t, &points[i].x, &points[i].y, &points[i].z ) == 4 )
{
    i++;
}
fclose(fp);

int n;


for (n=0; n<=i; n++){

    printf("%c  %2.5f %2.5f %2.5f \n", points[i].t, points[n].x, points[n].y, points[n].z ); }


    printf("There are i = %i  points in the file \n And I have read n = %i  points ",i,n);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `char t[1]` and not a simple `char t`?

Comment: Seems like an excellent time to get acquainted with a debugger, if you are on a linux/unix/etc based system I can recommend GDB!

Comment: @Fredrik : I recommend DDD

Comment: You should check fp for even be valid.

Answer (score 8):

Since there's only 1 char in there, not a string just use a single char in your code:

```
    char t;
}Point;
```

Then when you read it in:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%c %f %f %f ", &points[i].t, &points[i].x, &points[i].y, &points[i].z ) == 4 )
{
```

I'll note that having an array of 1 char, at the end of a structure, sets you up for the [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) which might not have been your intentions... A good reason to use just `char t` instead of `char t[1]`

Also this line:

```
for (n=0; n<=i; n++){
```

Should be

```
for (n=0; n<i; n++){
```

One last note... if you wanted to print the character out that you read in the prints at the bottom, you should be using `n`:

```
// note your previous code was points[i].t
printf("%c  %f %f %f \n", points[n].t, points[n].x, points[n].y, points[n].z ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
  while(fscanf(fp, "%c %f %f %f ", points[i].t, &points[i].x, &points[i].y, &points[i].z ) == 4 )
    {
    i++;
}
fclose(fp);

int n;


for (n=0; n<i; n++){

    printf("%c  %2.5f %2.5f %2.5f \n", points[n].t, points[n].x, points[n].y, points[n].z ); }


    printf("There are i = %i  points in the file \n And I have read n = %i  points ",i,n);
getch();
return 0;

}
```

modification are since only a single character is read `%s` modified to `%c` also in printf its not `points[i].t` its `points[n].t` . Also the limit checking in for loop is also corrected to `n<i`