# Parsing and nested pointers

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, ascii, structure

I am trying to write a program that reads a file containing tetrahedrons formatted as such:

```
    T 109 20 10 19
   [T X1 X2 X3 X4 ]
    T 123 34 24 33
    T 182 83 82 92
```

Where each number X in each row denotes a triplet (of x, y and z coordinates) at line X of a data file :

```
line 1 x y z
line 2 x y z
  [.......]
line n x y z
```

I have posted a similar (but simpler) question here [Parsing data from ASCII formatted file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729035/parsing-data-from-ascii-formated-file-in-c) . This time round my idea is to read the tetrahedron file, and store the 4 line numbers representing the coordinates of the vertices of these tetrahedrons in an array `vertid[]` (0 through 3) and then linking the tetrahedrons to the vertices using an array of pointers to the `Vertex` structure. I'll summarise: Store line ID numbers in tetrahedron structure and then set pointers to "point" at the correct Vertex.

Please bear in mind that I am no programmer (I need this to generate a Voronoi diagram). Also would it be simpler if instead of storing the vertices that makeup the tetrahedrons, I stored the edges (as I believe I will actually require edge data rather than vertex data for the generation of the Voronoi D) ? 
I have spent my Sunday working on this and its not working and I haven't got a clue why.
Thank you.

(not working) example:

```
#define FILEPATHtri "/pathto/grid1DT.txt"
#define FILEPATHorg "/pathto/grid1.txt"
#define MAX  10000

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "math.h"



typedef struct
{

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    char ID;
}Vertex;

/* NOT USED ATM
        typedef struct {
            edge_ref next[4]; // pointers to other edges (AQE data structure)
            void *data[4]; // pointers to endpoints of edge
            unsigned ID; // ID of edge
          }Edge;
 */
typedef struct
{
    Vertex *vert[4];
    int vertid[4];
    char t;
}Tetra;

void file_link (void)
{

    Vertex *vert_dt = malloc( MAX * sizeof (Vertex) ) ;

    Vertex *vert_std = malloc( MAX * sizeof (Vertex) ) ;

    Tetra *tetrahedron = malloc(MAX * sizeof (Tetra) );

    FILE *fp1,*fp2 ;
    fp1 = fopen( FILEPATHtri,"r");
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp1, "%c %i %i %i %i ", &tetrahedron[i].t, &tetrahedron[i].vertid[0], &tetrahedron[i].vertid[1], 
            &tetrahedron[i].vertid[2], &tetrahedron[i].vertid[3] ) == 5 ) // Saving the line numbers into vertid[0..3]
    {
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp1);


    fp2 = fopen( FILEPATHorg,"r");
    int j = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp2, "%f %f %f ", &vert_std[j].x, &vert_std[j].y, &vert_std[j].z ) == 3 ) 
    {
        j++;
    }
    fclose(fp2);

    int n;

    for (n=0; n<i; n++) {

        tetrahedron[n]->vert[0]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[0] ]; // retriving coords from the standard file and storing
        tetrahedron[n]->vert[1]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[1] ]; // them in the vertex pointer array of tretrahedron
        tetrahedron[n]->vert[2]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[2] ];
        tetrahedron[n]->vert[3]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[3] ];
    }
        int m = 100; //used to retrieve m'th tetra, so that I can print the tetra that I want,just for checking purposes..   

        // printing 13 variables in total... 
        printf("These are the 4 coordinates of the vertices of the  %i th tetrahedron from the DT file %f %f %f\n%f %f %f\n%f %f %f\n%f %f %f\n", n, 
                tetrahedron[n]->vert[0]->x,tetrahedron[n]->vert[0]->y,tetrahedron[n]->vert[0]->z,
                tetrahedron[n]->vert[1]->x,tetrahedron[n]->vert[1]->y,tetrahedron[n]->vert[1]->z, 
                tetrahedron[n]->vert[2]->x,tetrahedron[n]->vert[2]->y,tetrahedron[n]->vert[2]->z, 
                tetrahedron[n]->vert[3]->x,tetrahedron[n]->vert[3]->y,tetrahedron[n]->vert[3]->z);

    free(vert_dt);
    free(vert_std);
    free(tetrahedron);
}

int main(void) {
    file_link();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format is similar to .obj format, which is not too hard to parse. You had it pretty good; your errors are mostly just typos at this point.

Just use data in-place instead of pointers:

```
Vertex *vert[4];
```

becomes:

```
Vertex vert[4];
```

You'll also need to change all of your '->' notations to dot (.) notation, e.g:

```
    tetrahedron[n].vert[0]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[0] ]; // retriving coords from the standard file and storing
    tetrahedron[n].vert[1]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[1] ]; // them in the vertex pointer array of tretrahedron
    tetrahedron[n].vert[2]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[2] ];
    tetrahedron[n].vert[3]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[3] ];
```

and your testing code should bring n back down one (it's currently lastLine+1):

```
    // printing 13 variables in total... 
n--; // n must be last entry
```

Finally, I got a compile error on your allocations, and had to type cast them:

```
Vertex *vert_dt = (Vertex*) malloc( MAX * sizeof (Vertex) ) ;

Vertex *vert_std = (Vertex*) malloc( MAX * sizeof (Vertex) ) ;

Tetra *tetrahedron = (Tetra*) malloc(MAX * sizeof (Tetra) );
```

Note that fscanf() is pretty strict, so an input file with, say, extra leading spaces might confuse the program. I tested these changes on made-up files, so no guarantees.

Hope this helps! Here's my full file:

```
#define FILEPATHtri "grid1DT.txt"
#define FILEPATHorg "grid1.txt"
#define MAX  10000

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "math.h"



typedef struct
{

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    char ID;
}Vertex;

/* NOT USED ATM
        typedef struct {
            edge_ref next[4]; // pointers to other edges (AQE data structure)
            void *data[4]; // pointers to endpoints of edge
            unsigned ID; // ID of edge
          }Edge;
 */
typedef struct
{
    Vertex vert[4];
    int vertid[4];
    char t;
}Tetra;

void file_link (void)
{

    Vertex *vert_dt = (Vertex*) malloc( MAX * sizeof (Vertex) ) ;

    Vertex *vert_std = (Vertex*) malloc( MAX * sizeof (Vertex) ) ;

    Tetra *tetrahedron = (Tetra*) malloc(MAX * sizeof (Tetra) );

    FILE *fp1,*fp2 ;
    fp1 = fopen( FILEPATHtri,"r");
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp1, "%c %i %i %i %i ", &tetrahedron[i].t, &tetrahedron[i].vertid[0], &tetrahedron[i].vertid[1], 
            &tetrahedron[i].vertid[2], &tetrahedron[i].vertid[3] ) == 5 ) // Saving the line numbers into vertid[0..3]
    {
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp1);


    fp2 = fopen( FILEPATHorg,"r");
    int j = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp2, "%f %f %f ", &vert_std[j].x, &vert_std[j].y, &vert_std[j].z ) == 3 ) 
    {
        j++;
    }
    fclose(fp2);

    int n;

    for (n=0; n<i; n++) {

        tetrahedron[n].vert[0]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[0] ]; // retriving coords from the standard file and storing
        tetrahedron[n].vert[1]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[1] ]; // them in the vertex pointer array of tretrahedron
        tetrahedron[n].vert[2]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[2] ];
        tetrahedron[n].vert[3]=vert_std[ tetrahedron[n].vertid[3] ];
    }
        int m = 100; //used to retrieve m'th tetra, so that I can print the tetra that I want,just for checking purposes..   

        // printing 13 variables in total... 
        n--; // rewind to last tetrahedron
        printf("These are the 4 coordinates of the vertices of the  %i th tetrahedron from the DT file %f %f %f\n%f %f %f\n%f %f %f\n%f %f %f\n", n, 
                tetrahedron[n].vert[0].x,tetrahedron[n].vert[0].y,tetrahedron[n].vert[0].z,
                tetrahedron[n].vert[1].x,tetrahedron[n].vert[1].y,tetrahedron[n].vert[1].z, 
                tetrahedron[n].vert[2].x,tetrahedron[n].vert[2].y,tetrahedron[n].vert[2].z, 
                tetrahedron[n].vert[3].x,tetrahedron[n].vert[3].y,tetrahedron[n].vert[3].z);

    free(vert_dt);
    free(vert_std);
    free(tetrahedron);
}

int main(void) {
    file_link();

    return 0;
}
```